# Issue about three drop-down lists in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a page. That page is for registration. I have 3 drop-down boxes for country, state, and city. I want a simple scenario, when I select the country, then the state drop-down list must be filled with states of that country. Same for city. It means when I'll select the state, then cityDropdown must be filled with city names of that state. But the page should not postback. And selected values must be met at the server side.

What do I have to do? If this is possible by Ajax / JavaScript, please provide code. Or direct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AjaxcontrolToolkit cascading drop-down list does it for you, [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx).

See this example, http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/02/ajax-cascading-dropdownlist-database.html.